# Is everyone using Edge (Chromium) noticing accesses to *.gotechcheck.com?

Tags: browser, ublock-origin, ublock

One or two months ago, I began to try the new Chromium-based Edge - and at this point, I couldn't be more satisfied - never touched Chrome again, although it's unavoidable that, for some given tasks, both are very similar, as it happens with any Chromium-based browser - well, that's what we have today.

Well, I am also an uBlock user. This last week, I've noticed that, out of nothing, every site tries to access `*.gotechcheck.com`. As I didn't find much info on this domain on the wild, **naturally I've blocked it on all sites**. I also use Waterfox for my personal stuff, but no connection tries to this domain were done there or on my now rarely used Chrome.

So:

- anyone noticed it too? or is it something just on my side? don't
  remember installing any new extensions recently (but well, you never
  know)
- it seems like an Edge-only occurrence, but the question is
  surely valid for anyone on any browser and platform

Thank you guys for any info on this!

Comment: @John, thank you for the hint - I should have thought about it. :-( Although I couldn't find which one was the culprit, I turned them all off (except for uBlock), and then turned back on one by one. Didn't test it much yet, but so far, no mentions of that domain. If you could post your comment as an answer, I can accept it. Tks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please remove most maybe all extensions (at least until you know what caused the issue). I have Chromium Edge on three machines here with no extra extensions and no interference issues.